# Grid building for Connect Four gui

Tags: java, swing, paint, grid-layout

I have been able to create a grid using an image file (serves as the empty circles), a loop, and GridLayout, but I am well aware that there's more functionality needed (like for dropping the token, though no animation is necessary yet) so I scrapped it and now I'm back to an empty grid. I am stuck and I'm not really sure how I can accomplish this. My code is a mess at the moment so I'm not sure if it'd even make sense for me to post it.

My main problem is how to build a grid, which will then just be filled with a solid color (I'm cancelling using an image file, it seems a little more complicated as far as I'm concerned) with empty circles, that I will be able to fill up with an image file of a token once the player clicks on a button that corresponds to the column he chose (and then reset everything after the game is over). In other words, a rectangle of solid color and with empty circles to be filled up by tokens, but not with solid color, but an image file.

I have been trying to familiarize myself with `paint()` but I only started learning GUI last week so there are still likely some more things I'll have to learn to probably understand it in a considerable degree.

I am running out of options tantamount to my knowledge of GUI (Swing in particular) and I have been trying to work on this for a week now.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple possible ways to solve this, but one easy one is to give a JPanel a GridLayout, and then fill it with JLabels with ImageIcons that show empty circles. When the column is selected, the appropriate JLabel is given a new ImageIcon via `setIcon` that shows a color filled circle.

Also,

- Always strive to separate your program logic code from your GUI code, since the better your separation, the easier will be your ability to debug and enhance.
- Work on small problems one at a time. Don't move on to the next problem until the current small step is solved.
- Work out your logic and ideas on paper first before committing it to code.
- Don't "work with paint". If you need to do Swing graphics, you'll want to override a JPanel or JComponent's `paintComponent` method. The paint method also concerns itself with drawing borders and children, and so overriding it can have nasty and unexpected side effects on these. Also paint is not double buffered by default, and this can lead to bad animation once you start working with animation.

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> Will it be okay to use JButton though? Because that was what i used during my first attempt. I can use setIcon with it too right?

Do you mean use a JButton instead of a JLabel? That would work, and yes you can call `setIcon` on JButtons, but would make all your rectangles look like buttons. So if that's OK, then do it. Otherwise, you could still use JLabels, and then create a row grid of JButtons to put below or above your game grid, and then have the user press those buttons, and in their ActionListeners have them change the icons of a JLabel in the selected column.

But having said this, I mainly recommend that you use what works best for you. The learning will be in the creating, no matter what you create.

---

**Edit 2**
You ask:

> do you think it'll be possible/a nice approach to store jlabels in an array and then lay them out in a panel?

Absolutely, either an array of `JLabel[]` or a `List<JLabel>` I think is not only possible but in fact essential for this to work well. I think that you're definitely on the right track here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll go try it and for now I'll just vote up your answer while I'm waiting for other ones. 
And yeah thanks for pointing that out, I did mix up my logic code with my GUI code. I'm new to this so no doubt I'm still messing up, but I'll try to reorganize. Thanks again :)

Comment: Will it be okay to use JButton though? Because that was what i used during my first attempt. I can use `setIcon` with it too right?

Comment: Thanks for that, JLabels sound better. But I hope you won't mind me asking this on here also: do you think it'll be possible/a nice approach to store jlabels in an array and then lay them out in a panel? so far, it's the way i prefer and could think of to control the jlabels and use `setIcon` to "fill them up" with the tokens upon an event from the user. Hope you won't mind sharing your opinion on this